# How to get a value out of a string by compare two strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, string, function, parsing

I think my question (above) is too broad. Let me try to explain here...

Say I have 5 departments in a string:

```
"Accounting ResearchDevelopment **InformationTech** System FrontOffice"
```

and I have another string like this:

```
"John is in **InformationTech** department"
```

The value is `InformationTech` because this value matches in two strings.

How do I get a value `InformationTech` out of those two strings with no or minimal for-loop?

Comment: Looks like homework to me. What did you try so far?

Comment: First of all, I'd say you're almost certainly doing something wrong if you're having this problem in the first place because this is a terrible way to manage data. Unless this is a homework assignment or something like that, in which case are there any other constraints? Like, is "no or minimal for-loop" a rule for the assignment?

Comment: GottZ, I tried for-loops but it is long.  I am looking for a shortcut ... perhaps .include() or .map() or .search() something like that but I am new to this.

Comment: Use an array to store your data instead of a string.

Comment: just check for the word with a pair of `**` around...

Comment: @MisterJojo That wasn't in the original string, I'm pretty sure they were just using that for emphasis before you added the code formatting.

Comment: elfantoche, ok, let's say I join a string into an array on both strings. How do I get a value that one word is matched?

Comment: @JohnFine see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the departments never contain spaces, you could split the strings and then use `filter()` to extract the duplicates:

```js
let string1 = 'Accounting ResearchDevelopment InformationTech System FrontOffice';
let string2 = 'John is in InformationTech department';

let arr1 = string1.split(' ');
let arr2 = string2.split(' ');

let matches = arr1.filter(val => { return arr2.indexOf(val) != -1; });

console.log(matches);
```

The above also supports multiple matches, and will return an array containing the shared words.

Comment: BenM, Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this example will help you.

```
"John is in InformationTech department".split(' ').filter(word => "Accounting ResearchDevelopment InformationTech System FrontOffice".split(' ').includes(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same like BenMs solution but I changed the filter a bit.

```js
let string1 = "Accounting ResearchDevelopment **InformationTech** System FrontOffice"
let string2 = "John is in **InformationTech** department"

let strings1 = string1.split(' ');
let strings2 = string2.split(' ');

let solution = strings1.filter(s1 => strings2.includes(s1));

console.log(solution);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution :)

```js
let string1 = "Accounting ResearchDevelopment **InformationTech** System FrontOffice"
let string2 = "John is in **InformationTech** department"

let result = string1.split(' ').filter(str => {
    return string2.indexOf(str) > 0
})

console.log(result);
```